# Variable changing gives me syntax error "Can't assign to operator"

Tags: python

I'm coding a text-based game in Python on a site called 'repl.it', and while trying to change a variable, I came upon this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 526
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I'm a newbie at python, and I can't understand much, so I just want someone to fix the code and tell me how this works.

Here's the code:

```
#Adding hits or misses
if decision == "t3" : mothershiphit = mothershiphit + 1
elif decision == "t2" : jetdown = jetdown + 1
else: mothershipmiss = mothershipmiss + 1, mothershiplanded = mothershiplanded + 1

print " "
```

[Link to the game:](https://repl.it/@Some_random_turtle/Text-based-UFO-war-game) It's not finished yet, but I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a comma (,), use a semicolon (;) to separate the statements in a single line.

```
if decision == "t3": mothershiphit = mothershiphit + 1
elif decision == "t2": jetdown = jetdown + 1
else: mothershipmiss = mothershipmiss + 1; mothershiplanded = mothershiplanded + 1
```

**Explanation**

With the comma, the interpreter will think that is doing the following:

```
mothershipmiss + 1, mothershiplanded = mothershiplanded + 1
```

As you can see, in the first line you're actually adding + 1 to the operator (what's on the left) and this is not valid.

With the semicolon, the statement would look like this instead:

```
mothershipmiss = mothershipmiss + 1
mothershiplanded = mothershiplanded + 1
```

Which is valid, as you're assigning 1 to the element on the right.

Comment: Even better: Use multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you in that. I didn't wrote that in the answer as it wasn't the exact thing the user asked but it'll sure make the code more readable.